# Cannot install ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 following install guide on Windows 8

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, windows-8

I'm trying to install ArcGIS for DEsktop 10.2, I get to the following screen:
[image: arcgis for desktop install screenshot]

But any of the instructions highlighted in blue do not open, the mouse hovers over them changing their colour to darker blue as if you can click and open, but nothing opens. I can't go through with the install. I thought there might be a problem with the download so I downloaded the file 'Arc GIS for desktop 10.2, from esri online again, using my authorisation codes. The file is 2GB. After downloading the program for install, the only .exe file is written ESRI.exe. I click this and receive the screen as shown in the screenshot above in my post. Both times I have not benn able to continue with the install as not setup links open. There has never been another version of ArcGIS for desktop on this computer.

I have CORE i7, 64 bit, Windows 8, 16GB RAM.

I did simulataneously download the ArcGIS desktop tutorial and the DBMS files, I didn't run any of those. I read the .net 35 has to be installed first, when I ran that, no options opened in any windows, other than to say can this program modify your computer? to which I answered yes. Here is a screen shot of all the downloads I did, I just want to get the ArcGIS for desktop going. I'm completely inexperienced:
[image: ArcGIS desktop 10.2 downloads]

Comment: are they .iso files? I can't read the file names. Speaking for ArcGis 10.1 there's an install in the \Desktop folder called 'setup.msi' which can be used like: msiexec /I setup.msi

Comment: In 10.2.1 the setup is in \Desktop\SetupFiles\Setup.msi. ISO files can be opened with 7-zip or mounted using Daemon tools or similar. You might need to check your .net and prerequisites manually but the hyperlink on the esri.exe is just a shortcut to this file.

Comment: adding to @MichaelMiles-Stimson comment run as administrator (7zip) too see the support issue http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38074

Comment: Also adding to @MichaelMiles-Stimson - in Windows 8, no need to extract or use Daemon tools - Win8 will mount an ISO as a CD drive natively.